# The origin of list data structure

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, linked-lists, lists

Does anyone know when the list data structure was mentioned in computer programming/algorithms? Who gave birth to this list concept?

Comment: What do you mean by list? Is it [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type))?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knuth gives a good overview on the history of lists and linked data structures. From *The Art of Computer Programming*, Volume I, Section 2.6:

> Linked memory techniques were really born when A. Newell, J. C. Shaw, and H. A. Simon began their investigations of heuristic problem-solving by machine.

Answer (score 3):

The first use of linked lists in their modern form seems to have been by Peter Luhn in 1953, when he implemented a chaining-based hash table on the IBM 701 machine.

Linked lists are often misattributed as being due to Newell et al. during their development of the IPL language (an early version of lisp), but that wasn't until 1956. The IPL language did *popularize* linked lists, however. It just didn't invent them.

A good reference is pages 457 and 458 of Knuth's Art of Computer Programming Vol 1.

Answer (score 2):

List processing is simultaneously three things in the
development of computer science. (1) It is the creation
of a genuine dynamic memory structure in a machine
that had heretofore been perceived as having fixed
structure. It added to our ensemble of operations those
that built and modified structure in addition to those
that replaced and changed content. (2) It was an early
demonstration of the basic abstraction that a computer
consists of a set of data types and a set of operations
proper to these data types, so that a computational
system should employ whatever data types are appropriate to 
the application, independent of the underlying
machine. (3) List processing produced a model of designation, 
thus defining symbol manipulation in the
sense in which we use this concept in computer science
today.

Computer Science as Empirical Inquiry: Symbols and Search (1975 Alan Turing Award Lecture - Allen Newell and Herbert A. Simon)